# Setting fragment id programmatically with transaction fails in Android

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have 3 fragmets that I add to a viewpageradapater and then to the viewpager within a method in my MainActivity, below a piece of code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements FragmentCommunication {

...
       @Override
       protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            ...

            ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

            Resources res = getResources();

            adapter.addFragment(new FragmentOne(), res.getString(R.string.fragmentOneLabel));
            adapter.addFragment(new FragmentTwo(), res.getString(R.string.fragmentTwoLabel));
            adapter.addFragment(new FragmentThree(), res.getString(R.string.fragmentThreeLabel));
            viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

            ...
        }

... 
...
    public void GetFragmentAndDoStuff(float[] values) {
        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();

        FragmentOne fragOne = (FragmentOne) fm.findFragmentByTag("my_fragmentone");
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

I will focus on FragmentOne only from now on as an example.
My layout for FragmentOne is a Relative Layout with some textviews:

activity_fragment_one.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="mypackage.Fragments.FragmentOne">

    <TextView .... />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and its java class associated is (a piece of it):

```
public class FragmentOne extends Fragment {
  ...
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_fragment_one, container, false);

        view.setId(R.id.reservedFragmentOneID);

        FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
        // Transaction start
        FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
        ft.add(view.getId(), this, "my_fragmentone");
        // Transaction commint
        ft.commit();

        return view;
    }
  ...
}
```

My resource file with the reservedFragmentOneID:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <!-- List of reserved IDs -->
    <item name="reservedFragmentOneID" type="id"/>
</resources>
```

When I try to commit the transaction within onCreateView, it crashes and stop working. I also have tried to use container.setId(...) and container.getId() instead of using view and I get the same behaviour.

So, What am I doing wrong?

Below the exception thrown:

```
Can't change tag of fragment FragmentOne{41f9e470 #1 id=0x7f0d0070 android:switcher:2131558512:0}: was android:switcher:2131558512:0 now my_fragmentone
```

Finally, once I get to commit it successfully I would like to get the FragmentOne by its tag or ID within my MainActivity as below code shows. I am not sure if I will get the correct fragment (FragmentOne) using the code above or a null instead..., so is it correct?

Comment: What's the exception?

Comment: See my edit, I have put the exception thrown.

Comment: Does R.string.fragmentOneLabel = "my_fragmentone"?

Comment: R.string.fragmentOneLabel is not "my_fragmentone". It is the label name that is shown in the tab in the UI. Why?

Answer (score 0):

May be `RelativeLayout` is not working with `fragment`

change parent of activity_fragment_one.xml `RelativeLayout` to `FrameLayout`

Comment: Using FrameLayout instead of RelativeLayout, I get the same exception as indicated.